# Grammar -- Nor without Neither but with Non

Tags: grammar, neither-nor, non-native-english

Is this sentence grammatically correct:

> Non necessarily convex nor simply connected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Non necessarily

Is probably a typo, and should be

> Not necessarily

Other than that, the sentence is fine, especially if you add a comma before "nor". You can use "nor" without "neither" to connect two negative sentences.

> I haven't travelled to Canada, nor am I planning to.

Nor is also used as a short answer to agree with a negative statement

> -- I don't smoke.
>
> --Nor (do) I. (a little too formal, I guess)

Comment: My comment is that "nor" has no place in the English language.  Its most common usage may be with "neither.". But "neither" means "not either," which does not need another negative.  "I do not like either spiders or snakes"; hence, "I like neither spiders or snakes."

Comment: My comment is that "nor" has no place in the English language.  Its most common usage may be with "neither."  But "neither" means "not either," which does not need another negative.  "I do not like either spiders or snakes"; hence, "I like neither spiders or snakes."  Furthermore, "I don't smoke."  "Neither do I."  ("I do not either"--precisely what you're trying to say.  "Nor" causes a double-negative to exist between the two sentences.)